# How to create url form in menu dynamic laravel

Tags: php, laravel, menu, infyom

I just want to know how create condition in laravel if url field / form in menus is true then in menu href will linked into $url, unless if url form is null, then in menu href will linked into $id just as usual.

my blade menu child :

```
<ul>
@foreach ($childs as $child)
<li><a href="/categories/{{$child->id}}">@if (count($child->childs)) @endif</a></li>
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="/categories/{{$child->id}}">{{$child->nama}}@if (count($child->childs)) @endif </a>
        @if (count($child->childs))
            @include('menuChild', ['childs'=> $child->childs])
        @endif
</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your code into this

```
<ul>
    @foreach ($childs as $child)
    <li><a @if (request($child->link, true))href="{{$child->link}}"@endif></a></li>
    {{-- <li><a href="/categories/{{$child->id}}"> @if (count($child->childs)) @endif</a></li> --}}
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="/categories/{{$child->id}}">{{$child->nama}}@if (count($child->childs)) @endif </a>
        {{-- <li class="dropdown"><a href="/categories/{{$child->id}}">@if (count($child->childs)) @endif </a> --}}
            @if (count($child->childs))
                @include('menuChild', ['childs'=> $child->childs])
            @endif
        {{-- </li> --}}
    </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: it works, but i've changed algorithm a little bit code on condition if request, but anyway thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @afadaarugia if what he proposed solves what you shared initially as an issue you can accept his answer and help him get reputation

Comment: No problem mate, just ask what you need here! @afadaarugia